# Simplify and improve for loop

Tags: r

I wondered if there exists a simpler (and possibly more efficient) way to write the following loop

```
l = leg(u[1],k)
for (i in 2:length(u)){l=rbind(l,leg(u[i],k))}
```

where `leg` is a user-defined function that returns a vector of size k. Basically, I want to return a `length(u)` x `k` matrix.

My issue is that the computation is very slow when `length(u)` is big, so maybe using some smarter functions (like apply or its variants) would make it faster.

Comment: Maybe this can be more efficient: `l <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(u),function(i)leg(u[i],k)))`, anyway you should consider to make your `leg` function more vectorized (if possible), i.e. able to accept full `u` instead of `u[i]`

Comment: Pre-allocation of the matrix can also improve:
`l<-matrix(nrow = length(u),k)`
`for (i in 1:length(u)){l=l[i,](l,leg(u[i],k))}`

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, `sapply` is not necessarily faster than a `for` loop

Let's test a few different methods with `microbenchmark`

```
library(microbenchmark)
u<-1:10
k<-3
```

I invent here a function for the sake of testing:

```
leg<-function(u,k){u**(1:k)}
```

Let's test different methods:

```
 method1<-function(u,k){
   l = leg(u[1],k)
   for (i in 2:length(u)){l=rbind(l,leg(u[i],k))}
 }
 method2<-function(u,k){
  l<-matrix(nrow = length(u),ncol = k) 
  for (i in 1:length(u)){l[i,]<-leg(u[i],k)}
 }
 method3<-function(u,k){
   l <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(u),function(i)leg(u[i],k)))
 }
```

Now :

```
microbenchmark(times = 100, method1(u,k),method2(u,k),method3(u,k))
           expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
method1(u, k) 30.031 32.6920 36.88837 34.2125 41.4350 53.219   100
method2(u, k) 21.668 25.8490 29.60131 27.1800 32.6915 70.705   100
method3(u, k) 21.667 26.2295 29.42637 27.3700 33.0715 51.699   100
```

If we vectorize our function:

```
leg2<-function(u,k){
  result<-matrix(nrow = length(u),ncol = k); 
  for(i in 1:k){result[,i]<-u**i}
}
microbenchmark(times = 100, method1(u,k),method2(u,k),method3(u,k),leg2(u,k))

Unit: microseconds
        expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
method1(u, k) 28.891 31.1710 34.79391 32.692 37.8235 64.243   100
method2(u, k) 20.527 24.7085 29.20205 26.229 31.3610 79.068   100
method3(u, k) 22.428 24.7090 28.49507 26.610 31.1710 71.465   100
leg2(u, k)  6.462  7.6030  9.03213  8.363  8.7430 19.768   100
```

So about 3 times faster!